# Getting a value from a different class

Tags: java

I have a main class named `main.java` and 3 classes in a package `f.java`, `graphics.java` and `image.java`

I have a private int R in f.java, with `setR()` and `getR()` there

Now i need to get that value (from getR()) in `graphics.java`

I need to get an interface linking those 2, or is just a cast problem?

Try to get me some code for graphics.java so i can get that value!

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Show us some sample code.

Comment: show us the code for `f.java`

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13212555/TP6.zip

here's the project (some stuff written in Portuguese)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an interface to do what you want as long as the getter and setter for R are public. That is the idea of getters and setters. Of course in order to get R, you need to have an instance of the class `f` that it is an attribute of.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to an instance of an `f` object to your instance of your `graphics` object. From your `graphic` object you should then be able to call `getR()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you want to return a private variable, right ?

If yes follow this example which declares a variable 'sum' and returns it:

```
 private double sum = 0;

  public double getSum()
  {
       return sum;
   }
```

Then to call getSum() method create an object of the class that returns that method & displays it , like this:

```
  FileProcessor anObject = new FileProcessor();

  System.out.println("Returned value is: "+anObject.getSum() );
```

Note: Use Java code conventions; classes names must be like this, not a single letter & must be meaningful:

```
FileProcessor.java //manipulates a file
```